# update or insert based on a condition in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning php, I work on a small project for restaurant. In servants page when I try to take order, first I check the existence of the food in the order list if the food is already exist in the table so the quantity of the food will update otherwise if the food is not exist in the order list so it will be add to (tbl_temp_order),but it gives me error.
how can I fix it?
I appreciate your help.

```
if (isset($_POST[$row['fid']])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['tableId'])) {
        $table = $_SESSION['tableId'];
        $foodId = $row['fid'];
        $returnQTY = checkQty($foodId);
        //If the quantity was bigger than 0 in (order table) it just increases the quantity and updates the record
        $state = 0;
        if ($returnQTY) {
            $qty = '';
            $qty++;
            $updateQty = "update tbl_temp_order set qty='$qty' where fId='$foodId'";
            mysqli_query(getConnection(), $updateQty);
        } else {
            //but if the quantity for this food in (order table) was '0' so it will insert new record.
            $qty = 1;
            $insert = "insert into tbl_temp_order(fid,tid,qty,state)value ('$foodId','$table','$qty','$state')";
            mysqli_query(getConnection(), $insert);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting...

Comment: Instead of image, copy/paste your code.

Comment: I would first check if this is correct `$_POST[$row['fid']` ... mostly if you post someting its not giving in `row` unless ou specificly created an array with `$row` with that particular `fid`.  Also, your code is open for sql injection, better use prepared statements.

Comment: @basta also .. your definition of  `$qty = '';`  is wrong. since you request the variable to be upped by 1, the value should be  `$qty = 0;` That part doesnt even make sense btw to me. you unset it and add then 1 to it. which is what you do in the else as well. So it makes no sense here.

Comment: Thank you all for your help I fixed all the errors and bugs

Comment: btw, spelling error in the insert statement, its `values` not `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution for this - use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` query. You need to create/update table `tbl_temp_order` with primary/unique index `fid`:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_temp_order` (
    fid int primary key,
    tid int,
    qty int,
    state int
);
```

and use next query:

```sql
insert into `tbl_temp_order` (
    `fid`, `tid`, `qty`, `state`
) values (
    ?, ?, 1, 0  /*`qty` = 1, `state` = 0 by default*/
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `qty` = `qty` + 1;
```